# Migration with spring boot 3 to native image is causing Code generation does not support [...]PersistentEntities exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore, graalvm-native-image

We’re having a running Spring Boot 3 Service and try to make them run as a native image in GCP. In our service we’re using the following build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '5.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${3.1.0}"
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.20'

    *
    *
    *
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

*
*
*

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    *
    *
    *
    
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: 3.1.0

    implementation platform("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:$4.4.0")
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub', version:4.4.0
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore', version:4.4.0
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore', version:s4.4.0
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-logging', version:4.4.0

    *
    *
    *
    
    }

    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.0.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: 3.1.0
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: 3.1.0
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: 3.1.0
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: 3.1.0
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: 3.1.0
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: '3.0.0'

    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '5.3.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: 3.1.0
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '6.1.0'

    *
    *
    *
}

lombok {
    version = "1.18.26"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

bootRun {
    systemProperty("spring.aot.enabled", "false")
}

  *
  *
  *
```

The service is running on the latest spring boot version, and we’re using for our GCP dependency the latest version with 4.4.0. Now having all the important dependencies on the latest version we added the graalvm.buildtools to our plugins. A smaller service with less dependencies and no connection to a database (Datastore in our case) worked with these changes out of the box. In this service all steps until the aot-compiler are executed and during the aot compiler we’re getting this error message:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Code generation does not support org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities`

The service doesn’t uses actively this library but the further analysis brings up that the GCP datastore library is using it. I was expecting a few issues with configurations or reflections, but for this generic exception, I don’t have an idea. Now the question is, did some have a similar issue or any idea how to solve it?

We tried to use different versions of the `com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencie`  but non of them solved the issue. The next step we tried was to add the latest specific version for spring.data to the project this also not brings us further.

Comment: Google Support told me that at the moment there is no support for native images with the GCP client library. This GitHub request can maybe provide the information if it's solved in the future: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1279#issuecomment-1273276899 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1565